# I want to use a font awesome icon inside of a php block

Tags: php

I want to use a font awesome icon inside of a php block

```
echo '<form action="like.php?post_id=' . $post_id . '" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" class="comment_like1" name="like_button" value="Like">
                <div class="like_value">
                    '. $total_likes .' Likes
                </div>
            </form>

echo '<form action="like.php?post_id=' . $post_id . '" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" class="comment_like1" name="like_button" value="Like">
                <div class="like_value">
                    '. $total_likes .' Likes
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: This question can use more context. I'm particularly unsure about "font awesome icon". Perhaps elaborate more on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  echo '<form action="like.php?post_id=' . $post_id . '" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" class="comment_like1" name="like_button" value="Like">
            <div class="like_value">
                '. $total_likes .' <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            </div>
        </form>'
```

Comment: I want to add an icon button instead of the word 'Likes'

Comment: I figured out the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Chordz then post the answer